Is there a way to transfer a comment to an answer?
I recently answered a question on the main site, and soon after my answer was moved to a comment. I've since edited the answer to be more informative and specific to the question that was asked. 
The additional information is pertinent to the question and I'd like to vote to restore the post, but a warning says that "a moderator has deleted the post and it cannot be undeleted." 
Should I just edit the comment? Can the comment eventually be transferred back to an answer?

FYI, I converted the answer to a comment as it was attracting flags because it lacked citations. The improved version looks great, and I would have restored it myself if a different moderator hadn't beaten me to your flag.

There's no need to transfer the comment or make a new answer; the old, edited answer can be restored, though it requires a moderator. Just flag the deleted post to be undeleted, explain in the flag (use the Other) option that you think you've fixed the problem which caused the post to be deleted.
You can't personally undelete an answer deleted by a moderator, but any moderator can undelete the answer, they just need the post to be brought to their attention (via a flag is the traditional way).
